Control Ninja options in cmake --build command
I am happily using cmake and ninja,
I have a script with several cmake commands:
cmake dir1 && cmake cmake --build . && ctest
cmake dir2 && cmake cmake --build . && ctest
cmake dir3 && cmake cmake --build . && ctest
...

I can switch to Ninja by simply adding export CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja at the top of this script.
How can I pass options to the ninja command without changing the lines of the script?
I am looking for something like this:
export CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja
export CMAKE_PASS_NINJA_OPTIONS="-l 5"   # <-- this option doesn't exist, it is for illustration

cmake dir1 && cmake cmake --build . && ctest
cmake dir2 && cmake cmake --build . && ctest
cmake dir3 && cmake cmake --build . && ctest
...


Cheat and add a $PATH entry with a ninja command that sticks the required commands in front and launches the real ninja?

Maybe there is an option to specify the specific ninja command, to which to pass also the options, there is a CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM option after all. I didn't find the ninja equivalent.

There is no such option. You can specify extra Ninja options 1)  in the cmake --build invocation, 2) in the nativeToolOptions part of a build preset, or 3) creating a ninja shim that adds the argument. (or overriding CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM to such a shim)

@Botje, so I can pass thru ninja options to build? can you explain #2?  if you make your comment an answer Incan accept it. also, cmake_make_program can choose the path (and options?) to ninja but it is overwritten by -G at the start of the configuration step.

solution 2 does not meet your requirements, you have to call cmake with a --preset flag.
